# DAO Layer test: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, spring-data-jpa, dao

I try to run test for my DAO Layer with Spring Boot. But I receive
  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Configuration error: found multiple declarations of @BootstrapWith for test class [com.example.demo.FoodDaoIntegrationTest]`

I've read a couple of answers to this error, but it still hasn't helped. I guess there is still some kind of problem with annotations. 
My test is:

```
package com.example.demo;
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = com.project.application.DemoApplication.class) 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = com.project.application.DemoApplication.class) 
public class FoodDaoIntegrationTest  {

@Autowired
private TestEntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
private FoodDao mealDao;

@Test
public void TestSomething() {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a chaos in your annotations. You can't mix SpringBootTest and DataJpaTest

Try this:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
@DataJpaTest
public class FoodDaoIntegrationTest  {
```

Comment: If I try to delete SpringBootTest and ContextConfiguration I'll get .IllegalStateException: Unable to find a@SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use ContextConfiguration or SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test.

Comment: and If I keep ContextConfiguration I would get UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.FoodlDaoIntegrationTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mealDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type..

Comment: Where is your DemoApplication in the package structure? You should always keep the Application class in a root package above all the other classes